# return value is null sometimes in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm receiving value in JSON format by calling a simple select query.
I'm using `AsyncTask` for that.
The problem is sometimes it's working fine but sometimes the `response_value` is null without any change.
What should I do?
What am I missing?

CODE OF **`doInBackground(String... strings)`**

```
URL url = new URL(GetUrl.URL_MAIN_CATEGORIES_DATA);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String response_value = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response_value += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return response_value;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: try loggin the exception in your catch blocks instead of printing stack trace. Log.e("Yourtag","Exception occurred",e);    .... You might be getting an exception but you can't see it with the stack trace on android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try logging the exception in your catch blocks instead of printing stack trace.

```
Log.e("Yourtag","Exception occurred",e);
```

You must be getting an exception but you can't see it with the stack trace on android. That's the only way that it can work sometimes and other times it won't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But as I said it doesn't happen all the time. So what type of exceptions I can expect? What are the possible reasons?
Internet connection,server load? what?

Comment: There can be a number of reasons, say your connection got cut off, timeout of request,say a server refused your connection etc You will never know what exception has hit without Logging it. stack traces don't show in android as there is no terminal exposed. Log it and you can handle the response according to your logic

Comment: Thanks,I'll do that. 
How can I collect bug data from users in the easiest way while they are running the app in their devices?

Comment: Check out Firebase crashlytics and Firebase Analytics... they are good for bug stack traces from remote devices and logging events respectively. please accept the answer if it solved your doubt. And do remember to remove the logs from release app as they will not print in a release app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.
I'll definitely try those.